# Masstransit and RabbitMQ permissions

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

I am trying to figure out Masstransit 2.9.9 and RabbitMQ 3.4.3.  I have RabbitMQ installed on a server and am trying to get a simple console application from my desktop to send a message.  I created another administrator login.

I keep getting permission errors and the bus won’t initialize.

ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication mechanism PLAIN. For details see the broker logfile.

When I look in the log files, it seems to  use guest even when I send another login.

```
IServiceBus bus = ServiceBusFactory.New(sbc =>
            {
                sbc.UseRabbitMq(r =>
                  {

                      r.ConfigureHost(new Uri("rabbitmq://server/vhost/queue"), h =>
                      {
                          h.Validate();
                          h.SetUsername("user");
                          h.SetPassword("pwd");
                      });
                  }
                sbc.ReceiveFrom("rabbitmq://server/order_queue");
}
```

I saw something about maybe  needed to configure ssl for rabbit but i'm not sure.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After banging my head, it appears the rabbit client that comes with the masstransit rabbitmq nuget package is slightly out of date.  I did an update and the code works.  The only change was to remove queue from the configurehost

```
r.ConfigureHost(new Uri("rabbitmq://server/vhost"), h => ....
```

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem (I am testing first time Masstransit & rabbitMq). I added username and password in Uri:

```
new Uri("rabbitmq://user:pwd@server/vhost/queue")
```

I think that your ReceiveFrom address needs username and password. Also vhost is needed.

```
sbc.ReceiveFrom("rabbitmq://user:pwd@server/vhost/order_queue");
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion.  I did try that, but it didnt work.  passwords in the uri are no longer supported